# Draw on HTML5 canvas and use the drawing as a div

Tags: html, html5-canvas, paperjs

Is it possible to draw on the canvas using HTML5 and other js libraries and use the resulting drawing as a div?

I am interested in achieving a box (for starters) that is not drawn by regular css borders, but by a shape drawn on the canvas. Is that possible? And how?

I found paper.js on google, but that is all about drawing. How to use that drawing as a div in regular HTML (5) is my question.
Thank you

Comment: Canvas is just an element like any other. You could create a div which contains a canvas element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`canvas` is a DOM element in which you can draw arbitrary vector and raster graphics. `div` is another type of DOM element that can contain other elements, like `canvas` for example.

The graphics that you draw in a `canvas` elements are **not** DOM elements that you can interact with the same way as `div`, `span`, `p`, `table`, etc. So I think the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it for me. But do I understand that if I use a div, put inside it a canvas, then I can draw on that canvas while still being able to put other elements on top of it?

Comment: Like for example, I make a rectangular div 400x400px. Then inside it I place a canvas element on which I draw something... I can still use that drawing as a background for my div, right?

Comment: I will answer myself with this http://jsfiddle.net/jarble/U72dt/8/ (found in another question here). Thank you for your time.

Comment: If this is not the correct answer, then you should not accept it and answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw your shape on canvas (using paper.js or plain JavaScript) then extract it as an image which you set as background to a div or other element.

Just have in mind that you need to update the background if the div's size changes.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    div = document.getElementById('myDivElement'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    cs = getComputedStyle(div),
    w = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width') , 10),
    h = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height') , 10);

canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;

/// draw something on canvas
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f90';
ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

/// set as background:
div.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + canvas.toDataURL() + ')';
```

### [Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/QkKwk/)

Just note that many things can affect the div size such as padding, margin, box-sizing, borders etc. These you need to take into account when you are calculating the size of the canvas. The better option is in many cases to use `box-sizing: border-box;` for the CSS rule of the element in question.